# How to extract sentiment from Yahoo finance message board?

Tags: programming, yahoofinance

Does anyone know if it is possible to write a software to pull Yahoo message board sentiment for a specific stock?

Any API from Yahoo or anyone has done it before?

Comment: This is very vague... Have you done any research about it? How would you tackle the problem? This is very close to be off-topic as "too-broad" but I'll let the community decide

Comment: you'd probably have to build a custom web scraper in python or sometihng....than parse it accordingly.

Comment: Try `Yahoo Query Language` (YQL).

Comment: That question has two parts: how do you effectively get messages and their metadata (timestamp, username) from a yahoo finance message board (pure programming exercise) and part two - how do you extract sentiment from that. Which is so extremely broad it is not even funny to start.

Comment: Maybe you want to try Sentiment Classifier, which works well on Finance text such as this one https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/finance-text-sentiment. I have been successfully using this API to make trades based on News headline sentiment for certain stocks and bitcoin and getting a great ROI.

Answer (score -4):

you can use opinion finder tool or gpoms tool to conduct sentimental analysis

Comment: Can you use those tools directly to do sentiment analysis on _Yahoo_?